# How to intersect two different axis along the common axis on Chartjs?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Let's say we have 2 different dataset like:

```
{
  name: "Voltage",
  samplingTime: 0.1,
  data: [
    3598.599878, 
    3598.595369, 
    3598.580042,
    ...]
}
```

and

```
{
  name: "Velocity",
  samplingTime: 0.1,
  data: [
    0.01, 
    0.03, 
    0.06,
    ...]
}
```

Assume that they have common time (x) axis. I managed to display data with two Y axis and time axis. What I want to do is to intersect these two (Velocity and Voltage) axis along this common time axis. So I want Voltage to be X Axis and Velocity to be Y axis and I don't want time axis to be shown.
How can I make this possible ?

This is how my addData function looks like:

```
this.data.datasets = datas.map((data, i) => ({
        label: data.name,
        data: data.data,
        backgroundColor: bgColors[i],
        borderColor: borderColors[i],
        borderWidth: 1,
        yAxisID: data.name,
        xAxisID: "Time"
      }));
```

**Note: I tried changing datasets' yAxisID and xAxisID but I couldn't find the solution**

Answer (score 0):

To use both datasets as separate axes, you just need to map your data like this :

```
data : [
  {x:3598.599878, y:0.01},
  {x:3598.595369, y:0.03},
  {x:3598.580042, y:0.06},
  ...
]
```

Then in your options, make sure your X axis type is `linear` :

```
options : {
  scales:
    {x:
      { type:'linear', ...}
    }
}
```

This is because X axis type is `category` by default, and both your datasets are numeric, so after mapping, you will end up with only 1 dataset, and you can set the chart type to be `line`, `bar` or `scatter`.